# How to define the input_shape in Keras according to the dimensions of the input data?

Tags: python, keras

I'm about to create my very first model on my own. After performing several tutorials I encounter that this is not as straight forward as I expected. However. 
At the moment I wonder about how to define the dimensions of the input_shape. I got several complainments about wrong dimension inputs for the layers. I adjusted some numbers and now I can compile but I didn't really understand what I did respectively I would like to know how to define the input_shape properly.
My input is a numpy array which I generated from a dataframe with 16 variables but to get started I use only one respectively two (one is a time column). At first, I thought the dimensions would be

```
X_train1.shape
(1700, 2)
```

but this did not work. Then I decided to take a number of two which worked until the last layer which consisted of only one neuron. Hence, I got an according error telling me that the layer expected an input of dimension two instead of one. So I increased the number of neurons to two and now it is working.
But, as far as I know, an output layer with two neurons is only used for classification purposes which I am not aiming at.

**TL;DR:** How to define the input_shape, especially when not using images as input (which is almost always the case in each tutorial..)?

The actual network is according to this [tutorial](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/build-your-first-neural-network-model-on-a-structured-dataset-using-keras-d9e7de5c6724):

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_31 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 6         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_32 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 3         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 4         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_34 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 6         
=================================================================
Total params: 19
Trainable params: 19
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

```
type(X_train1)
numpy.ndarray

# shape of input
X_train1.shape
(1700, 2)

# Build model
model= Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(2,), activation= "relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation= "relu"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation= "relu"))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.summary() #Print model Summary

# Compile model
model.compile(loss= "mean_squared_error" , optimizer="adam", metrics=["mean_squared_error"])

# Fit Model
model.fit(X_train1, y_train1, epochs=2)

X_train1
array([[-1.73103225e+00,  1.67925250e+00],
       [-1.72899455e+00,  1.70540111e+00],
       [-1.72695684e+00,  1.51829725e+00],
       [-1.72491913e+00,  1.22942045e+00],
(...)
       [ 1.72491913e+00, -1.34502350e+00],
       [ 1.72695684e+00, -1.21882561e+00],
       [ 1.72899455e+00, -5.57245295e-01],
       [ 1.73103225e+00,  3.86950632e-01]])
```

data frame:

```
    timestamp   A_phsA
2018-02-05 14:00:00 1.517839e+09    856.436487
2018-02-05 15:00:00 1.517843e+09    859.653339
2018-02-05 16:00:00 1.517846e+09    836.635463
2018-02-05 17:00:00 1.517850e+09    801.097284
2018-02-05 18:00:00 1.517854e+09    794.855960
... ... ...
2018-05-01 08:00:00 1.525162e+09    563.391437
2018-05-01 09:00:00 1.525165e+09    602.101665
2018-05-01 10:00:00 1.525169e+09    648.061104
2018-05-01 11:00:00 1.525172e+09    695.000131
2018-05-01 12:00:00 1.525176e+09    715.601925

X_train1_raw = df_train1_raw.iloc[:, 1:2].values

for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X_train1_raw):
    X_train1, X_test1 = scaler.fit_transform(X_train1_raw[train_index]), scaler.fit_transform(X_train1_raw[test_index])
    y_train1, y_test1 = scaler.fit_transform(y_train1_raw[train_index]), scaler.fit_transform(y_train1_raw[test_index])
```